# Como renderizar uma função assincrona em reactJS?

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, react

Meu problema é o seguinte:

Tenho uma função assíncrona que faz uma requisição mysql e, dependendo do resultado da requisição, retorna uma DIV diferente.

```
const GetData = async(idAluno,disciplina) => {
  variavel = await confereInicial(idAluno, disciplina.id);
  //console.log(variavel); imprime direitinho, sem problemas
  
  if(variavel.data.length===0){
    return (
      <DivCheckBox dads = {dados} nomeDisciplina = {disciplina.title} labelDisciplina = {disciplina.label} id = {disciplina.id} inicial = {0}/>
    )}
  else{
    return (
      <DivCheckBox dads = {dados} nomeDisciplina = {disciplina.title} labelDisciplina = {disciplina.label} id = {disciplina.id} inicial = {1}/>
    )
  }

};
```

E essa função é chamada diversas vezes (atraves de um map) na parte de renderização da tela. Assim:

```
return (
    <div>
              
              {
              dados.state.nodesPadrao.map( (p) => {
                return (
                <GetData idAluno= {1} disciplina= {p}/>
              )})
              }

...
```

O problema é que quando compilo, ele aparece "objects are not valid as react child (found: object Promise). If you want to render a collection of children, use an array instead.

O que faço?

Comment: A pergunta que marquei é sobre React Native, mas os princípios são os mesmos (do React).  Pode usar `useState` e `useEffect`.

Answer (score -2):

Ter uma variável no state, onde você guardará os itens
e criar uma função para obter os dados do storage, chamando-a quando o componente é montado e renderizar o conteúdo a partir da sua variável do state

Comment: obrigado! poderia me dar uma luz de como eu poderia começar isso? talvez atraves do meu codigo